# Split video frambuffer

Tags: windows, linux, graphics

Is possible split the video framebuffer to display, for example, two logical screens in one monitor?

Is there an "standard" solution? Is there an proprietary solution, using nVida's or Ati's drivers?

The solution is possible in Windows or Linux?

Comment: You mean split it visually?  So you get two "framebuffer" devices on the left and right halves (or top/bottom) of the screen?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Must it be done at the framebuffer level or would it be acceptable to simply run two X clients in a custom window manager configuration?

Comment: yes, split visually. The idea is (in Windows) the display configuration window shows two screens instead of one. Is that possible?

Comment: In windows or linux?  That's still not very specific.  What is a "screen"?  A single instance of your app, or a whole desktop, or a complete virtualized machine, or what?  Broadly: yes, this kind of display is possible, but no, not at the video hardware level you're asking about.